# Access denied error when attempting to reference IIS Worker Process (related to IIS Smooth Streaming)

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, streaming

I'm trying to programmatically restart an IIS Smooth Streaming publishing point, and I'm getting stuck on an access denied issue. I'm leveraging the solution shown here: https://gist.github.com/opello/4073274

The issue I'm having is here:

```
WorkerProcess workerProcess = null;
     try
     {
        workerProcess = applicationPool.WorkerProcesses[0];
     }
     catch
     {
        Console.WriteLine( "Unable to find first Worker Process" );
        Environment.Exit( 1 );
     }
```

It's returning an access denied "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try running your program as Administrator?

Comment: This does work. I changed the AppPool running this site from "AppPoolIdentity" to run as the administrator account. This removed the access denied error.